# I can not convert Oracle query to SQL Server (to_date operator)

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a `select` query with Oracle syntax:

```
select 
    to_date(acdr.cdrdate||acdr.cdrtime,'ddmmrrhh24mi') call_date,
    regexp_substr(acdr.secdur,'([1-9]{1}[0-9]?+)') call_duration,
    regexp_substr(acdr.dialednum,'^2[0-9]{3}') operator_avaya_id,
    regexp_substr(callingnum,'^(996)[0-9]{9}') calling_number,
    acdr.acmcdr_id
from 
    avaya_cm_cdr acdr
```

and I need convert this query to T-SQL syntax.

I tried to convert this line

```
to_date(acdr.cdrdate || acdr.cdrtime, 'ddmmrrhh24mi') call_date
```

to this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(50), C, 102) call_date
```

and

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(acdr.cdrdate, acdr.cdrtime), 104) call_date
```

and I tried operator `cast` but it did not help.

operator  `CONCAT(acdr.cdrdate,acdr.cdrtime)` works normally and similarly `||` in Oracle. But I can not convert String to Date.

ERROR:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
select CONCAT(acdr.cdrdate,acdr.cdrtime) call_date from [avaya_cm_cdr] acdr
```

RESULT:

```
0112151647
0112151647
0112151647
0112151647
0112151647


CDRDATE varchar(6)
CDRTIME varchar(4)
```

Comment: not helped? did you get an error or unexpected outcome? You are actually converting that data to `VARCHAR` in SQL and `DATE` in Oracle so they are completely different things. What data type are those three fields (`c`, `cdrdate`, `cdrtime`) ?

Comment: If you are migrating a system from Oracle to SQL Server, _now_ is the time to get the data types right.

Comment: Can you please provide table schema in something like sqlfiddle?, thank you.

Comment: @ Juan Ruiz de Castilla I update quation

Comment: If you have the opportunity I strongly suggest you get the data type correct in your database. Those two fields should not be `VARCHAR` they should be `DATE` and `TIME`. Assuming you aren't going to fix the datatype, what should `0112151647` change to? is it 1st December 2015 or 12th Jan 2015? Please show the required result

Answer (score 0):

Does it help?

```
convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(acdr.cdrdate,5,2) + SUBSTRING(acdr.cdrdate,3,2) + SUBSTRING(acdr.cdrdate,1,2), 12) + convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(acdr.cdrtime,1,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(acdr.cdrtime,3,2) + ':00', 108)
```